# Seaborn: ValueError: No for palette='jet'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colormap

Running the following example from seaborn [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) with argument `palette='jet'`

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette='jet')
```

got the following error

```
    172         elif palette.lower() == "jet":
    173             # Paternalism
--> 174             raise ValueError("No.")
    175 
    176         elif palette.startswith("ch:"):

ValueError: No.
```

What's the reason for this error with the `jet` color palette ? I wonder if the error message can be more specific cause matplotlib [docs](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/colormaps.html#id7) states the following

> The often-used jet colormap is included in this set of colormaps. We can see that the  values vary widely throughout the colormap, making it a poor choice for representing data for viewers to see perceptually.

Comment: There's a whole Reddit thread that discusses this https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8psk37/til_that_seaborn_refuses_to_use_the_jet_color/

Comment: The issue that you just get "No" as an error message, and the fact that it's not very helpful has also been raised as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1435), with a predictable response.

Comment: @DavidBuck thanks for the references, actually this argument makes total sense "This can have the unfortunate side-effect of highlighting "features" in your data which may not actually exist!"

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn does not contain jet color palette. Better to go with Matplotlib or use custom color palette.
The available color schemes are
[image]