# python-colab :: Error when using : palette='jet' . why?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, scatter-plot, jet, palette

When I write the following code in Google colab, I get an error. what is the problem?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
n=200
x=np.linspace(-1,1,n)
y1=x**2
y2=np.sin(3*x)
y3=np.exp(-10*x**22)
sns.scatterplot(x=y1,y=y2,hue=y3,legend=False,palette='jet')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi - seaborn does not have a palette jet. Change it and that should work. Check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008798/seaborn-valueerror-no-for-palette-jet)

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code cause problem

```
sns.scatterplot(x=y1,y=y2,hue=y3,legend=False,palette='jet')
```

use this in place of above, it will give you proper output

```
sns.scatterplot(x=y1,y=y2,hue=y3,legend=False)
```

or

```
sns.scatterplot(x=y1,y=y2,hue=y3,legend=False, palette=None)
```